# I'm trying to get rid of spaces and convert a text file into a single line

Tags: java, regex, file, spaces

I was able to convert the text file input into a single line but could not get rid of the spaces no matter what I did and I've tried using .trim(), .strip(), and regex. 
Here is the original input(example.in):

```
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    ..B.......
    ..........
    .....R....
    ..........
    ..........
    .....L....
    ..........
```

My code:

```
    String in = Files.readString(Paths.get("example.in"));
    in=in.replaceAll("[\r\n\\s]+", " ");
```

Output:

```
    .......... .......... .......... ..B....... .......... .....R.... .......... .......... .....L.... ..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following regex converts all newline in empty string and tabs in spaces

```
in = in.replaceAll("\\n","").replaceAll("\\t"," ");
```

if you have other kind of white spaces then you can chain in the same way

**EDIT**

one more thing if you have consecutive spaces then chain `replaceAll("\\s+," ");`

in short you can say `in = in.replaceAll("\\n|\\t|\\s"," ");`

Comment: if still some problem occurs please tell me